# Clear X clipboard using cron

Tags: x11, cron, clipboard

Is there any way I can clear the X clipboard from a cron job? The usual commands for `xclip` don't seem to work.

```
echo -n | xclip -selection clipboard
```

doesn't work from cron.

Answer (score 2):

X programs use DISPLAYs to work out what X11 instance to apply the program to. If you are the sole user of your host then most likely your display will be `localhost:0` or often abbreviated to `:0`. you can find your DISPLAY variable by using:

```
echo ${DISPLAY}
```

To tell xclip to use that display, issue the `-display` command line option, or set the the DISPLAY environment variable

```
echo -n | xclip -display :0 -selection clipboard
```

Comment: A good answer, except that the default display is usually `:0`, and trying to use `:1` will result in an error.

Comment: Bad habbits! (I always have two X sessions, one is a VNC instance, and the other I rarely use). I should know better! I will update - thanks!